# In Jquery take a different values from single text box id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using Data Table in jquery. So i passed one input type text box and passed the single id. This data table will take a multiple text box. i will enter values manually and pass it into the controller. I want to take one or more text box values as an array..

The following image is the exact view of my data table.[image]
I have marked red color in one place. the three text boxes are in same id but different values. how to bind that?

```
function UpdateAmount() {debugger;
    var id = "";
    var count = 0;
    $("input:checkbox[name=che]:checked").each(function () {
        if (count == 0) {
            id = $(this).val();
            var amount= $('#Amount').val();
        }
        else {
            id += "," + $(this).val();
            amount+="," + $(this).val(); // if i give this i am getting the first text box value only.
        }
        count = count + 1;
    });



    if (count == 0) {
        alert("Please select atleast one record to update");
        return false;
    }
```

Really stuck to find out the solution... I want to get the all text box values ?

Comment: Do you want to add code instead of a picture and describe your expected results?

Comment: you need to add id's dynamically to each textbox, with that you can easily find out the solution or you need to send values to controller by sending this.id when the event occurs on that row

Comment: @PoliDev Its not actually correct to add same id to multiple elements. Try adding id's dynamically by incrementing a counter and you can access that id's using a simple for loop. Or else eliminate the id and access the textbox using the children attribute.I can give you the code if you like

Comment: Did you find a solution from the following answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the fundamental rule is that you must not have duplicate IDs. Hence, use classes. So, in your example, replace the IDs of those text boxes with classes, something like:

```
<input class="amount" type="text" />
```

Then, try the below code.

```
function UpdateAmount() {
    debugger;
    var amount = [];
    $("input:checkbox[name=che]:checked").each(function () {
        var $row = $(this).closest("tr");
        var inputVal = $row.find(".amount").val();
        amount.push(inputVal);
    });

    console.log (amount); // an array of values
    console.log (amount.join(", ")); // a comma separated string of values

    if (!amount.length) {
        alert("Please select atleast one record to update");
        return false;
    }
}
```

See if that works and I will then add some details as to what the code does.

Comment: if i give `var amount = [];
            var $row = $(this).closest("tr");
            var inputVal = $row.find(".amount").val();
            amount.push(inputVal);

            if (count == 0) {
                id = $(this).val();
                var x= id.split("-");
                var y = x[0]+"-"+ inputVal;
                id=y;
            }
            else {
                id += "," + $(this).val();
            }
            count = count + 1;
        });' this type of code, the second value is not binding...

Answer (score 2):

An Id can only be used once; use a class, then when you reference the class(es), you can loop through them.

```
<input class="getValues" />
<input class="getValues" />
<input class="getValues" />
```

Then, reference as ...

```
$(".getValues")
```

Loop through as ...

```
var allValues = [];
var obs = $(".getValues");
for (var i=0,len=obs.length; i<len; i++) {
  allValues.push($(obs[i]).val());
}
```

... and you now have an array of the values.

You could also use the jQuery `.each` functionality.

```
var allValues = [];
var obs = $(".getValues");
obs.each(function(index, value) {
  allValues.push(value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First if you have all the textbox in a div then you get all the textbox value using children function like this

```
function GetTextBoxValueOne() {
 $("#divAllTextBox").children("input:text").each(function () {
 alert($(this).val());
});
}
```

Now another way is you can give a class name to those textboxes which value you need and get that control with class name like this,

```
function GetTextBoxValueTwo() {
$(".text-box").each(function () {
alert($(this).val());
});
}
```